# Question concerning the proof that the subspace $X=\{0\} \cup \{1/n \,| \,n \in \mathbb{Z_+}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

> Proof. Given an open covering $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$, choose $U \in
>  \mathcal{A}$ with $0 \in U$. Since $U$ is open in the subspace
>   topology, there is an $N \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ such that $1/n \in U $ for
>   all $n > N$. For each $n ≤ N$ choose $U_n \in \mathcal{A}$ with $1/n
>  \in U_n$. Then $B =\{U, U_1,\cdots, U_N\}$ is a finite subcover of
>   $\mathcal{A}$.

I don't understand why does it need to be the case that if $0 \in U$, then an infinite number of points of $X$ are in $U.$

Comment: If an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ contains $0$, what more do you know about that open subset?

Comment: That it is the limit point of the set?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you ask why $0 \in U $ is necessary?

Comment: I'm asking why does $0 \in U$ imply that $1/n \in U$ for all $n > N.$

Comment: out of my head, the *cauchy sequence converges inside* $U$, else the sequence of $1/n$ would **not** converge inside $U$

Comment: @NikosM. So far in the book, we haven't studies Cauchy sequence.

Comment: ok, this is **not** so important just terminology, consider the sequence of $1/n$ , this sequence should converge **inside** $U$ and since the limit is $0$ $\implies 0 \in U$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ is open thus there exists an $\mathbb{\epsilon}> 0$ that $(-\mathbb{\epsilon},+\mathbb{\epsilon})$ is a subset of $U$.

So $\frac{1}{n}\in U$ is true for all $n$ that satisfy $\frac{1}{n}<\mathbb{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Add the condition $\epsilon>0$. Also change all $n$-s into something like all $\frac{1}{n}$-s. Then you will get an upvote